# I want my screenshot to be pasted into text input after CTRL+V, how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

1. We press PrtScn
2. Focusing input, pressing CRTL+V
3. Screenshot is being uploaded on server

---

How do i do that with jQuery or Javascript or smth else?

Thanks!

Comment: google it before please ;), sure it cant be done

Comment: -1 The desired behaviour is unclear, you can't "download" to a server without triggering some sort of serverside request.

You could mean I take a screenshot, paste it into an Input field (Why?) and then trigger an UPLOAD.

Comment: Im sorry used download instead of correct upload

Comment: In the input text field should be seen just a name of an image like "screenshot-date-time.jpg" while screenshot is being uploaded into /uploads/screenshot-date-time.jpg

Comment: I'll work on a solution using the API I've pointed at below. If you need an alternative, maybe make the question more specific and show what you've tried already

Answer (score 0):

I'll do my best to throw up an answer, whilst not actually throwing up at the poor quality of the question, because (possibly). There's something here.

PrtScn and Paste is a common way for getting screenshots into Word or Powerpoint or what have you, but just because there is a blinking '|' character, doesn't not mean this is the same as a focused `text` input.

There is however hope. (Soon)[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent).

I'm not going to write out an implementation, as I can see this question getting burned with fire pretty sharp-ish. If you want help, try something, work out what you are trying to do, share some sample code and post another, useful question.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ClipboardEvent

Update:
Ok I'll try and build something :) - Watch this space I guess.

I'm happy for answer to be deleted as incomplete, but it already offers a starting point so is at least more complete than the question in it's current format.